# How to convert minutes to hours and minutes (without days)

Tags: php, date, time, data-conversion

I would like to display time in minues as an hour and minutes.

**Example 1:** I want to display 125 minutes as a 2:05

I know I can to somethink like:

```
$minutes=125;
$converted_time = date('H:i', mktime(0,$minutes);
```

This works fine, but if the time is more then 24h it is a problem.

**Example 2:**

```
$minutes=1510;
```

and I want to receive 25:10 (without days), only hours and minutes.

How to do that?

Comment: `date` functions will not help you, because you're not working with dates! This is a trivial manual operation, mostly involving a `/60` operation.

Comment: please try to do a brief search before posting new questions ..

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can use:

```
$minutes=1510;

$hours = intdiv($minutes, 60).':'. ($minutes % 60);
```

<sup>**!!! This [only works](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intdiv.php) with php >= v7.xx**</sup>

Previous answer:

```
$minutes=1510;

$hours = floor($minutes / 60).':'.($minutes -   floor($minutes / 60) * 60);
```

Comment: $hours = floor($minutes / 60).':'.($minutes % 60);

Comment: but here something is missing. your answer is correct but not time format .my means was your answer come like 8:60 or 9:01 or 9:10. here hour value is single value. it will be better if it comes in form   09:23 like this way.. i posted my solution here you can check.

Comment: check my solution,                                                                                                                          
   $minutes=$item['time_diff'];
                    $hours =   sprintf('%02d',intdiv($minutes, 60)) .':'. ( sprintf('%02d',$minutes % 60));

Comment: When the minutes are in single digits, the solution provided by this answer does not make sense. Ex: For 67 minutes, it returns: `1:7`. Instead it should be `1:07`. Please include formatting with `sprintf` to correct the answer.

Answer (score 8):

As simple as that.

```
$minutes = 125;

$hours = floor($minutes / 60);
$min = $minutes - ($hours * 60);

echo $hours.":".$min;
```

**EDIT**: should use floor() instead of round() for getting correct results.

Answer (score 5):

```
$hours = floor($minutes / 60); // Get the number of whole hours
$minutes = $minutes % 60; // Get the remainder of the hours

printf ("%d:%02d", $hours, $minutes); // Format it as hours:minutes where minutes is 2 digits
```